# Triggering a link with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to programmatically trigger this link:

```
<a ui-sref="termGradesAssignment({sectionId: row.sectionid, termId: term.termid, studentNumber: config.studentNumber, schoolId: row.schoolid})" class="ng-binding" href="#/termGrades/assignment?schoolId=XXXXXX&amp;studentNumber=XXXXXX&amp;termId=MP1&amp;sectionId=XXXXXX">X</a>
```

*I "X"ed out some private information

I've tried and researched everything that I could think of but I'm still stuck. I know I have to somehow use Angular JS, but I have never had any experience with it and I tried to learn but I couldn't figure it out correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not enough shown or known. Also doesn't make sense using `href` and `ui-sref` on same element. Rather than triggering the click in the dom you probably should be thinking more along the lines of using `$state.go()` from inside controller

Comment: Take some time to read through [mcve] and [ask]